# Language Fallback doesn't work on some templates - enabled in Standard Values but not working on items

Tags: language-fallback

Language Fallback is enabled in my site; it works in many places so this isn't an issue of it not being globally enabled.

[image]

However I have one template that it's not working on. I created Standard Values, and checked off _Enable item fallback;

[image]

but when I view an item that uses that template, it's not working:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting this field to Standard Values on EN version of your `... App` item? Does it work on new items created with that template?